# I've decided not to cater for IE6 - What tasty CSS treats can I use?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Ok firstly, this is not a discussion on whether I should be catering for IE6. I'm sure there's hundreds of threads on S.O. where you can discuss the pros, cons, market shares, javascript shivs and all the other stuff that comes with it.

> Let's say I've put two fingers up to
>   IE6 and am ignoring its existence -
>
> what can I now do differently in the
>   way I style my pages?
>
> Pseudo-selectors?
>
> Parent/Child selectors?
>
> Other tidy stuff?

**What are the new freedoms that come with abandoning IE6?**

*I know some of you will be itching to tell me why i should support ie6 or about js fixes that mean I can use advanced selectors etc etc - Please don't waste your/my/our time!*

Comment: hah - NICE. I'd start with float: right (that always seems to not work in IE6)

Comment: http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-css

Comment: +1 for not caring about IE6.

Comment: you could start by checking the "what's new" docs for IE7, as that would be your main limitation now

Comment: If everybody had stuck two fingers up at IE6 when IE7 first came out, IE6 would have died a much quicker and less painful death.

Comment: Duplicate of http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5488/what-new-cross-browser-features-can-we-use-if-we-drop-support-for-ie6 ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> You can now start to use web standards...

With IE6 out of the way, you can start to use loads of really nice things. Below is a list of things **specific to IE6**.

**New features**

- Transparent PNGs (full 24 bit!)
- Use of [child selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#child-selectors) `div > p`
- User of [sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) `p + input`
- [min/max-width/height](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/width.html)
- [:first-line](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-firstline)
- [:first-child](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html)
- :hover (all elements)
- float: right
- [position: fixed](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html)
- Attribute Selectors (input[type="text"])
- Trust z-index again

**Bugs fixed in IE7:**

- [Peekaboo Bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/peekaboo.html)
- [Internet Explorer and Expanding Box Problem](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/expandingboxbug.html)
- [Quirky Percentages](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/percentages.html)
- [Line-height bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/lineheightbug.html)
- [Border Chaos](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/border-chaos.html)
- [Disappearing List-Background bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/ie-listbug.html)
- [Guillotine Bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/guillotine.html)
- [Unscrollable Content bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/unscrollable.html)
- [Duplicate Characters Bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/dup-characters.html)
- [IE and Italics](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/italicbug-ie.html)
- [Doubled Float-Margin bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html)
- [Duplicate Indent bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/floatIndent.html)
- [Three pixel text jog](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/threepxtest.html)
- [Creeping Text bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/creep.html)
- [Missing First letter bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/firstletter.html)
- [Phantom box bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/inlinelist.html)
- [31 style sheet limit](http://work.arounds.org/issue/33/ie-has-limit-31-stylesheets-web-page/) - although, you shouldn't *really* be affected by this, else you've got other problems!

**Non-technical things:**

- Save time and money
- Throw away 90% of CSS hacks

Comment: +1 from me for a selection of IE6 bugs, a list of new features and the non technical things. Excellent.

Comment: You should remove :first-line and transparent PNGs from that list.

Comment: `z-index` is still broken as well.

Answer (score 6):

Still really depends which browsers you do want to target. Still plenty of things to look out for.

Here's a list of unsupported features in IE6 you can now use:

- child selector ( div > p )
- adjacent sibling selector ( h1 + p )
- general sibling selector ( h1 ~ p )
- chained class selectors (
  .class1.class2 )
- attribute selector ( a[href] )
- descendant selector after :hover
  pseudo-class ( div:hover span )
- chained pseudo-classes (
  a:first-child:hover )
- :hover on non-anchor elements
- :first-child
- "virtual dimensions" (dimensions
  determined by top, right, left,
  bottom when position: absolute )
- min-height, min-width
- max-height, max-width
- transparent border color
- position: fixed
- background-attachment: fixed works
  only on the root element

A really good resource you can look at is http://caniuse.com/ for viewing what is supported where.

And finally - a list of IE6 bugs that were fixed in IE7 - [more info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649487%28VS.85%29.aspx)

- basic alpha-transparent png support
- css child selector
- !important more properly works
- :first-letter support
- partial click bug
- window.XMLHttpRequest became present,
  instead of ActiveXObject
- abbr tag is recognized
- select z-index bug is resolved as
  it's become window-less

Comment: firefox 2+, ie7+, chrome, safari

Comment: Firefox 2 has less than half a percent of market share. IE7 has less market share than IE6 and is dropping faster than IE6. If you can drop these browsers, you can do a hell of a lot more than if you're stuck supporting them.

Comment: @gdj - Interesting about ff2 though "dropping faster than" is one of those truely useless statistics. Up there with "fastest growing"...

Comment: "dropping faster than" isn't useless. You're creating your web site to deploy in say x months from now. What matters is browser market share when your web site launches, not now. Furthermore, a browser must have significant market share for sufficiently long after launch to make your effort worth it. So if IE7's market share is negligible a year from now, it might not be worth supporting it—depends on your priorities.

Comment: @gdj - "dropping faster than" doesn't imply will be negligible. Comparative statements based on growth are almost always misleading. If 14 people died from putting ipods up their bums I could say "Ipods are the fastest growing cause of death in the uk" becuase they have gone from 1 to 14 at a whopping 1400% growth

Comment: OK, IE7 usage is lower than and dropping faster than IE6 usage. Better?

Answer (score 3):

I've used this site to keep up with IE6 / ~IE6+ oddities / workarounds:

**http://work.arounds.org/**

You could review what is a work around on IE6, and pat yourself on the back that you don't have to do it anymore ;)  I think thats a 'treat' in itself.. time saved!

At least now you can focus 0 time on IE6, and more time on IE7, IE8 issues...

Answer (score 2):

Mostly the freedom is your time now that you don't have to deal with IE6 bugs but the big gain Greg didn't already mention is the extra relational selectors: `>`, `+`, and `~` (child and siblings) and not worrying about hasLayout so much.

[Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) will tell you what you can and can't do now.

Comment: cool, how do these work? `>` is child right?

Comment: While `div p` gets **all** child `<p>` elements of `<div>`, `div > p` only gets **direct** children.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're still choosing to support IE7, that will be your new baseline.

This IE team blog post describes the improvements IE7 made over IE6:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/08/22/712830.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

It mostly boils down to way less bugs to worry about (many CSS bugs, PNG transparency issues).

The new CSS functionality is limited but useful:

- background-attachment: fixed
- :hover on all elements
- fixed positioning
- min/max width/height
- selector improvements (child and attribute)