# I've decided not to support IE7; what JS/CSS/HTML features can I now use?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

{idea came from [I've decided not to cater for IE6 - What tasty CSS treats can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450853/ive-decided-not-to-cater-for-ie6-what-tasty-css-treats-can-i-use) but I wanted an IE7 version}

Ok firstly, this is not a discussion on whether I should be catering for IE7. I'm sure there's hundreds of threads on S.O. where you can discuss the pros, cons, market shares, javascript shivs and all the other stuff that comes with it.

> Let's say I've put two fingers up to
>   IE7 and am ignoring its existence -
>
> what can I now do differently in the
>   way I make my pages?
>
> Pseudo-selectors?
>
> Parent/Child selectors?
>
> Hardware-accelerated potato counting?
>
> Other tidy stuff?

**What are the new freedoms that come with abandoning IE7?**

*I know some of you will be itching to tell me why I should support ie7 or about js fixes that mean I can use certain things etc etc - Please don't waste your/my/our time!*

Comment: Are you basically asking what the new features in IE8 are?

Comment: If you abandon IE6,7,8 & FF<4 then you have virtually the whole of CSS3 spec. March '12 browser visitor stats: IE6=0.9%, IE7=2.5%, IE8=9.4%, FF<4 =4.5%. Out of all of those its probably only worth catering for IE8 users.

Comment: Have you looked at [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/)?

Comment: @Ozzy: Not really. Today's browsers still don't support half of the CSS3 spec.

Comment: @Ozzy - Ever looked how much css3 IE9 really implements? There is not much with virtually the whole

Comment: Well, it mostly supports the 10 features shown here http://www.w3schools.com/css3/default.asp. Then again IE9 hits about 5/10 but the other browsers hit much higher.

Comment: @steveax: Yes, but I'm pretty sure that there are more than the ones at http://caniuse.com/#compare=y&b1=ie+7&b2=ie+8.

Comment: @Ozzy: FYI, CSS3 has **more than 50 modules**. W3Schools doesn't even cover a proper subset; it seems to be picking at the most popular features people are talking about today.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn ahh okay... interesting.

Comment: Perhaps this will be useful: [CSS Improvements in Internet Explorer 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Should I bother writing an answer? I'm itching to do so since I stopped supporting IE7 last year, so I'm supporting IE8 at the very minimum now.

Comment: @BoltClock: Sure. The two 'answers' right now are just links - and neither link is complete.

Comment: You should probably write your own question, you know ;)

Comment: @BoltClock: Yeah, but the other question was pretty decent. BTW, until recently, I was relatively sure that you're not a unicorn. What happened? Did you get eaten alive by a wild meme?

Comment: @JavaAndCSharp: I suppose I was a little too happy on reaching 100k rep at the end of last month, and turned into a unicorn as a result :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 is touted by Microsoft to be, [among other things](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/19/internet-explorer-8-final-available-now.aspx), fully CSS2.1 compliant. However, a number of bugs have been found so it's not actually *fully* compliant, but of course that doesn't mean it hasn't gotten better from version 7.

Anyway, the following are some of the well-known features introduced to IE8 that weren't present in IE7 (*this list is by no means exhaustive*):

### JavaScript

- Basic implementation of [Selectors API level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api) (`querySelectorAll()`)
- Basic implementation of [cross-origin resource sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors) (cross-domain Ajax)
- Native JSON parsing capabilities
- DOM improvements (a probable cause of the fixes to CSS attribute selectors — see below)

#### JS APIs in HTML5

- [Cross-document messaging](http://dev.w3.org/html5/postmsg/#web-messaging)
- [Web storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage)
- [History traversal](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html#history-traversal)

### CSS

#### CSS2.1

- IE8 has caught up with all (most?) of the CSS2.1 enhancements that were added to CSS1 properties, a list of which you can find [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304082.aspx)
- Fixes to the box model with regards to [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins), [floating](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats) and [stacking](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index)
- [`inherit` keyword](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#value-def-inherit)
- [`outline` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#dynamic-outlines)
- [`white-space` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop) for `pre-wrap` and `pre-line`
- Full support for `display: inline-block` on any elements
- [`display: table`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html)
- [Generated content and automatic numbering](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html): the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, as well as `quotes`, `content`, the `attr()` function and CSS counters
- [Printing and paged media](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html): the `@page` rule now works with the page pseudo-classes, typographic `orphans` and `widows`, and page breaks are supported to some extent
- [`:active` and `:focus` pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act)
- [`:lang()` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#lang-pseudo)
- The obscure syntax issues that affected the sibling combinators, CSS2.1's `+` and CSS3's `~`, in IE7 have been corrected in IE8 (the `* + html` hack no longer works either)
- The obscure bug that affected only DOM updates for the adjacent sibling combinator `+` has been corrected in IE8
- The HTML attribute and DOM property issues that affected CSS2.1 and CSS3 attribute selectors in IE7 have been corrected in IE8
- Some obscure bugs related to specificity have been corrected; one example is with the various [dynamic pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#dynamic-pseudos) which I identified in IE6/7 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9367665/106224)

#### CSS3

- [`box-sizing` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing) in CSS3 for `content-box` and `border-box` (`padding-box` was originally [a Mozilla proposal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing) so it doesn't exist in IE; it wasn't added to the CSS3 UI spec until recently, and it's still at risk of removal as of the January 2012 Last Call Working Draft)
- Some CSS3 features have been present in IE and proposed by Microsoft long before they were retconned into their respective specs, including `@font-face`, `overflow-x`/`overflow-y`, `text-align-last`, `word-wrap` (now `overflow-wrap`), and ruby text

### HTML

- [`<abbr>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-ABBR) and [`<q>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-Q)
- [`<object>` fallbacks](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#edef-OBJECT)

### Miscellaneous

- Limited support for [Data URIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)
- [WAI-ARIA](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria) compliance for accessibility

And of course, some sources:

- [IE8's release announcement](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/19/internet-explorer-8-final-available-now.aspx)
- [CSS Compatibility and Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024.aspx)
- [CSS Improvements in Internet Explorer 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304082.aspx)
- [QuirksMode CSS compatibility tables](http://quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)
- [Feature support comparison between IE7 and IE8 at caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#compare=y&b1=ie+7&b2=ie+8)